# window.open cache problem

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I'm using ***window.open*** in a function to open a web page, which displays help for the 
current page.

The pages URL are stored in DB , some pages need authentication.

For these pages, the first time we call them the user has to authenticate, but if he closes the page and opens it another time , it's the cached page that is displayed.

I've try to add the time to the url, in order to not display the cached page

```
var oDate = new Date();
window.open(url+oDate.getTime());
```

But the browser is still displaying the cached url.

Any idea to resolve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: It really should be `window.open(url + '?x=' + new Date().getTime())`, unless there are other parameters; the point is that it's going to break the URL to just stick the date on the end like that.

Comment: that's what i'm doing actually,

It's a missing

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try explicitly adding meta tags to your page:

```
<!-- HTTP 1.1 -->
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store"/>
<!-- HTTP 1.0 -->
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
<!-- Prevents caching at the Proxy Server -->
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Set clearcache or clearsessioncache equal to yes as required:

window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes', 'clearcache=yes');

Comment: `clearcache` and `clearsessioncache` is Android/iOS WebView specific.

Answer (score -2):

Try this, if you want to open a new page, without caching problems... it seems to work for me:

```
function openGoogleLinkWithDummy()
    {
        var randNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*99);
        var str="How are you doing today? " + randNumber;
        window.open("http://www.google.com?q=cat&" + randNumber);
    }
```

It surely works if you want to load a external javascript file (from server side code, at example, you append a random number to the name of the zzz.js file and it seems like zzz.js?v=123) but the trick will be ok for your problem, too.

The browser sees a different "version" every time you click the link because of the dummy number appended to the end.

Bye!