# Phonegap - always open the url as fresh - no cache in inappbrowser

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, inappbrowser

I want to open my url always fresh - no cache. I'm using cordova 2.9 so I guess `clearcache=yes, clearsessioncache=yes` wont work but still this does not work in iOS even on the latest version.

Also I tried a solution that we only append a random number in the URL but still it does not work.

I followed the solution here: [window.open cache problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627163/window-open-cache-problem)

Have anyone find a solution on this problem?

`window.open('myURL', '_blank', 'location=no, clearcache=yes, clearsessioncache=yes');`

Append random number:

`var randNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*99);`

`window.open('myURL?v='+randNumber, '_blank', 'location=no, clearcache=yes, clearsessioncache=yes');`

Comment: same issue, got nothing

Comment: Did you get it resolved ? or still not

Comment: clearcache=yes, clearsessioncache=yes both are only for Android

Comment: For iOS, have try this: http://anexinetmobility.blogspot.com/2013/10/clearing-inappbrowser-cache-on-ios-with.html